# How to set up multiple fields as primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a table with fields

EmployeeID

blahblah

blahblah2

.....

RecordMonth

RecordYear

- so each employee should only have a matching entry for a month, year, Emp#.  How do I set up a table.

So how do I set up the table so that EmployeeID can be updated once a month but can never have two entries for a matching month and year?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use a **compound primary key**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable 
  ( 
     employeeid  INT, 
     blahblah    VARCHAR(255), 
     blahblah2   VARCHAR(255), 
     recordmonth DATE, 
     recordyear DATE, 
     PRIMARY KEY (employeeid, recordmonth, recordyear) 
  )
```

And if your table already exists, drop the old primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

And recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (employeeid, recordmonth, recordyear);
```

Comment: Hi, my db does not  let me drop the primary key with the error  `'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key')`

Comment: so one should `ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY id INT NOT NULL; ` first.

Comment: @DmitriyGrankin Yes. It's work for me

Comment: Will still be able to select based on either one of the three columns still?